# React Native sendAppEventWithName from NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

On the objective-c side I launch a modal that does some work and then executes a `NSOperation`. The `NSOperation` subclass calls `[self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"ImageUpdated" body:@{@"imageId": imageId}];` when the job completes. I have verified that this is getting called, but I am unable to have the observer receive the notification. I have a class that doesn't render anything but in `componentDidMount` I have:

```
NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('ImageUpdated', (json) => {
  console.log(json);
  const imageId = json.imageId;
  this.props.dispatch(loadPhoto(imageId));
});
```

But this code never gets executed. The class that subclasses `NSOperation` adopts the `RCTBridgeModule` protocol and has `@synthesize bridge = _bridge`.

Anything to try would be appreciated.

**Update**
It seems that if you don't call into the class that is emitting the event then the `bridge` is nil and thus can't fire the event. I am going to see if I can instantiate my own bridge.

Comment: Everything looks good. I tested this on a new sample project and was able to get the event fired on the JS side. Maybe check that the event is not triggered before the listener is registered?

Comment: It isn't possible for the code to be hit that triggers the event before it registers. I have the component in the app`s render method as I always need it to listen. Then you have to select a few things and it will then trigger the event. I am on 0.27 not sure which version you used.

Comment: I tested it on RN 0.27.2

Comment: I added an update to my question but it seems like if you don't call `sendAppEventWithName` from the module you called into initially, then you can't use the bridge.

Comment: Could you share some more of your code? You don't really need to instantiate your own bridge, the bridge instance is valid as long as you have a RCTRootView, and if you keep a strong reference to it, it will remain valid and can be called anywhere.

Comment: I ended up solving it by using a class that registers for `NSNotification`'s and then dispatches events from there. I found that if you call a random module that isn't tied to an `RCTRootView` then you can only use the bridge from within that class or by it's reference.